# after saying that y=[example], i use list.remove(y) python doesn't remember what i assigned y to

Tags: python

in a while loop, i assigned y to a random value in a list

`y=[random.choice(list)]`

afterwards I need to remove  y from the list:
`list.remove(y)`
but it gives: ValueError: `list.remove(x): x not in list`.
If I write a word from the list instead of y, it obviously does work.

the entire while loop is (this should return a list of randomly chosen songs, all used once):

```
def playRandomized(songList):
    x=[]
    while len(songList)>0:
        y=[random.choice(songList)]
        x=x+y
        q=[songList.remove(y)]
        q=[songList]
    return x
print (playRandomized(list))
```

Comment: What is the variable `q` for?

Comment: Why is everything encased in a list? The issue is y is a list rather than the element

Comment: Your error code says remove x not y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`y` is a list, with one element, the content you want to remove:

```
def playRandomized(songList):
    x = []
    while len(songList)>0:
        y = random.choice(songList)
        x.append(y)
        songList.remove(y)
    return x
```

Since you want to add every element of `songList` in random order, you can just use `shuffle`:

```
def playRandomized(songs):
    random.shuffle(songs)
    return songs
```

Answer (score 2):

`random.choice` returns an item of list. so you can refactor the code like on the following.

```
item = random.choice(lst)
lst.remove(item)
```